# C#: retrieve the first n records from a DataTable

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a `DataTable` that contains 2000 records.

How would you retrieve the first 100 records in the `DataTable`?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Wow, what's with all the SQL answers? No one have their coffee yet?

Comment: I am using framework 2.0, and i am not using sql server

Comment: @Gaby - If you are not using SQL Server, then what are you using? MySql, Oracle, DB2, Postgres, something else all together?

Comment: Well, i am getting my records from sharepoint, where you can't query the first n records or do any limitation. All i want is to get first 100 record from my datatable without doing loops..

Answer (score 11):

If it implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var first100 = table.Take(100);
```

If the type in question only implements IEnumerable, you can use the Cast extention method:

```
var first100 = table.Cast<Foo>().Take(100);
```

Comment: I'm just jealous, I'm stuck on 2.0 myself too :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works for DB2.

```
select * from table
fetch first 100 rows only;
```

Answer (score 0):

and for mysql: `select * from table limit 100`

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/copydatatable.asp), but restrict the foreach loop to 100 records.

Answer (score 0):

And to make the list full, here is the statement for MS SQL:

```
Select top 5 * from MyTable2
```

And some other methods with MS SQL [can be found here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3532226/TOP-Clause-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm).

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the top *n* records in C# using the 2.0 framework:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var myRows = new List<DataRow>();

//no sorting specified; take straight from the top.
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   myRows.Add(dt.Rows[i]);
}
```